# Why doesn't the main() function run when I start a Python script? Where does the script start running (what is its entry point)?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I have this code:

```
import sys

def random(size=16):
    return open(r"C:\Users\ravishankarv\Documents\Python\key.txt").read(size)

def main():
    key = random(13)
    print(key)
```

When I try running the script, there are no errors, but nothing appears to happen. I expected it to print some content from the key file, but nothing is printed.

What is wrong? How do I make the code run?

Comment: This version of the question seems more popular and got somewhat better answers, so I reversed the direction of duplicate closure and fixed the question a bit.

Answer (score 36):

You've not called your main function at all, so the Python interpreter won't call it for you.

Add this as the last line to just have it called at all times:

```
main()
```

Or, if you use the commonly seen:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It will make sure your main method is called only if that module is executed as the starting code by the Python interpreter. More about that here: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

If you want to know how to write the best possible 'main' function, [Guido van Rossum (the creator of Python) wrote about it here.](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829)

Answer (score 13):

Python isn't like other languages where it automatically calls the `main()` function. All you have done is defined your function.

You have to manually call your main function:

```
main()
```

Also, you may commonly see this in some code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Probably people didn't like that the second code example had no proper explanation. As is it might as well be magic code. Mind you no one else here did either, but there is one useful link in LegoStormtroopr's response.

Answer (score 5):

### Something does happen, it just isn't noticeable

Python runs scripts from top to bottom. `def` is a statement, and it executes when it is encountered, just like any other statement. However, the effect of this is to **create** the function (and assign it a name), *not to call it*. Similarly, `import` is a statement that loads the other module (and makes *its* code run top to bottom, with its own global-variable context), and assigns it a name.

When the example code runs, therefore, three things happen:

- The code for the `sys` standard library module runs, and then the name `sys` in our own module's global variables is bound to that module
- A function is created from the code for `random`, and then the name `random` is bound to that function
- A function is created from the code for `main`, and then the name `main` is bound to that function

There is nothing to call the functions, so they aren't called. Since they aren't called, the code inside them isn't run - it's only used to create the functions. Since that code doesn't run, the file isn't read and nothing is `print`ed.

### There are no "special" function names

Unlike in some other languages, Python **does not care** that a function is named `main`, or anything else. It will not be run automatically.

As the Zen of Python says, "Explicit is better than implicit". If we want a function to be called, we have to call it. The only things that run automatically are the things at top level, because those are the instructions we explicitly gave.

### The script starts at the top

In many real-world scripts, you may see a line that says `if __name__ == '__main__':`. This is **not** "where the script starts". The script runs top to bottom.

Please read [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/) to understand the purpose of such an `if` statement (short version: it makes sure that part of your top-level code is skipped if someone else `import`s this file as a module). It is **not** mandatory, and it does **not** have any kind of special "signalling" purpose to say where the code starts running. It is **just** a perfectly normal `if` statement, that is checking a slightly unusual condition. Nothing requires you to use it in a script (aside from wanting to check what it checks), and nothing prevents you from using it more than once. Nothing prevents you from checking whether `__name__` is equal to other values, either (it's just... almost certainly useless).

Answer (score 3):

There's no such `main` method in python, what you have to do is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the function.  Put `main()` at the bottom of your code.