# Main function doesn't run the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

im new in the community !
im trying to run a function with main function and its not working for me.
when im calling to the function it is work pretty good and with the main function calling its not.
pleae help me to solve my problem.

```
def main():
    is_valid_input()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

def is_valid_input():
    """
    this function will check if the the guess is ok
    :param letter_guesses: the user's guess
    :type letter_guesses: str
    :return: True if the guess is complies with the rules and False if not
    :rtype: bool
    """
    letter_guessed = input("please guess a letter").lower()
    import string 
    if letter_guessed.isalpha() and len(letter_guessed) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

i added a pic with the problem[image]

Comment: define valid_input before the `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Rather than a typo, this should be a duplicate: [Why doesn't the main() function run when I start a Python script? Where does the script start running (what is its entry point)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257631)

Answer (score 2):

In script mode, your `is_valid_input` function is undefined when `main()` will be run. Place this block at the very end of your code (after the definition of `is_valid_input`):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Regarding your code *per se*, I am not sure what you want to do exactly, but below is a way to make the `is_valid_input` function only test an existing string:

```
def main():
    letter_guessed = '' # initialize invalid
    while not is_valid_input(letter_guessed):
        letter_guessed = input("please guess a letter: ").lower()

def is_valid_input(letter):
    """
    this function will check if the the guess is ok
    :param letter_guesses: the user's guess
    :type letter_guesses: str
    :return: True if the guess is complies with the rules and False if not
    :rtype: bool
    """
    import string 
    if letter.isalpha() and len(letter) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the problem not solve

Comment: @שלוחבה then please provide the whole traceback with error (did you get a `NameError`?)

Comment: instead of giving true or false it is giving the guess. " please guess a lettert "  i didnt get an error

Comment: that's because you're using input which excepts the user to enter a letter before executing the next line.

Comment: so how can i fix it ?

Comment: if `is_valid_input` is supposed to validate an existing string, you should move out the `input` part, but this is a different question than originally asked

Comment: when i moved out the input part the same problem happend . (how can i share my new code here ?)

Comment: @שלוחבה  have a look at my example, this **might** be what you want, if not, please edit your question

Comment: i added a picture

Comment: the picture doesn't help, I personally don't understand your problem if any, please check my code and explain in detail how it eventually doesn't work as you want and what you want

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. when i used main function in my code the result of the is_valid_input is the guess the user is put in the input. when i call to the function without using the main function it is working great  - the result is True or False. why it is happend ? why main function is disruptive the code ?

Comment: I don't get the behaviour that you describe. You function always returns True or False.

Comment: so unfortunately when i put the main function its not return anything.  just when i change the return to print its print true or false but i want to use return not print.