# my code works without using the def function but doesn't work with it

Tags: python

here is my code

```
def help():
    f = input()
    print (f)
```

it works without def and doesn't work with it in place. I tried many different simple codes like this but received no output whenever I used def. I am using VS code.

Comment: You've to `call` the `help` function after `defining` it as:

help()

Comment: did you call the function at all after putting it in the function? call `help()` at the same indent level as `def help()`.

Comment: `def`is just _defining_ the function. So you can call it later. If you don't call it, well... it works, but you're not asking it to do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the main() function run when I start a Python script? Where does the script start running (what is its entry point)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257631/why-doesnt-the-main-function-run-when-i-start-a-python-script-where-does-the)

Comment: Your code defines a function, but does nothing with that function, it is never called. so there will be no output, since the code in the function never executes

Comment: What is the question here? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

Once a function is defined, you have to call it to make something happen.

```
def help():
    f = input()
    print (f)

help()
```

Note that it may still seem like its doing nothing because you don't prompt for data. You'll need to go to the terminal window and enter a string. Better, include a prompt with your input so you know what to do.

```
def help():
    f = input("Input data to print: ")
    print (f)

help()
```

Comment: +1, Further reading for the OP [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function but never calling it. You need to define it like

```py
def help():
    f = input()
    print(f)
help()
```